# Custom column on django-tables2 that mix multiple foreignkeys

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am trying to make a custom column on django-tables2 with a function that returns the field that is not empty from 3 possibles foreign keys (just one can be not empty). Here is what I've done:

Models.py

```
class Sitiocancelado(models.Model):
    x = models.OneToOneField(X, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    y = models.OneToOneField(Y, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    z = models.OneToOneField(Z, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    fecha_de_cancelacion = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    comentarios = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.z.y.x.nombre_del_sitio
```

Tables.py

```
class SitiocanceladoTable(tables.Table):

    def columna_combinada(table):
        if x == None:
            if y == None:
                return z
            else:
                return y
        else:
            return x

    Sitio = tables.Column(columna_combinada)

    class Meta:
        model = Sitiocancelado
        attrs = {
            'class': 'table table-striped table-bordered', 
            'id': 'example', 
            'width' : '100%', 
        }
        fields = ('Sitio',)
        exclude = ('id', 'slug', 'sitioproyecto', 'sitiocontratado', 'sitiooperando',)
```

Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really how custom columns work. You basically have two options:

### [`render_<columnname>`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods)

This looks a bit like your example. Define a column and a method on the table class with name `render_<column name>`. No need to supply that name to the column you defined. Your example would look like this:

```
class SitiocanceladoTable(tables.Table):
    Sitio = tables.Column(empty_values=())

    class Meta:
        model = Sitiocancelado

    def render_Sitio(self, record):
        if record.x == None:
            if record.y == None:
                return record.z
            else:
                return record.y
        else:
            return record.x
```

This method is good for one-offs. It is not much extra code, and the code is very close with the rest of the definition of the table.

Note that I added `emtpy_values=()`. This will make sure your custom implementation of the render function used, even if django-tables2 thinks your column is empty. It's the responsibility of the custom column to render a proper default.

### [Subclassing `Column`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#subclassing-column)

If you need the functionality of this column in multiple tables, or multiple times in the same table, it might be cleaner to subclass `Column` or one of the more [specific `Column`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#columns) implementations.

Your example might look like this:

```
class CombinedFKColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, record):
        return getattr(record, 'x', getattr(record, 'y', getattr(record, 'z', self.default)))

class SitiocanceladoTable(tables.Table):
    Sitio = tables.CombinedFKColumn(empty_values=())

    class Meta:
        model = Sitiocancelado
```